# java selenium : want to make a purchasing bot . im having problems with the JavaScript button on the page

Tags: java, html, selenium

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get('https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/shop/geforce/?page=1&limit=9&locale=en-gb');
WebElement notify = driver.findElement(By.id('cookiePolicy-btn-close'));
notify.click();
WebElement buyButton = driver.findElement(By.className('featured-buy-link link-btn'));
buyButton.click();
```

Comment: <a class="featured-buy-link link-btn brand-green cta-button js-add-button" href="javascript:void(0);">Add to cart</a>

Comment: What are you trying to do? `WebElement buyButton = driver.findElement(By.className("featured-buy-link link-btn")); buyButton.click();` doesn't explain the problem at all, nor does it seem to attempt to.

Comment: I'm very sorry i haven't explained  it properly  i want to make a purchasing bot. but having trouble pressing the buy button on the page . i have managed to make it press the cookie button .it would not let me post the html so i have posted it above and now below

Comment: it is the 2080 TI buy button . also the 2060 buy button <a class="featured-buy-link link-btn brand-green cta-button js-add-button" href="javascript:void(0);">Add to cart</a>